# Improve speed of SQL view joining multiple tables, all with primary keys

Tags: sql, query-optimization, data-warehouse

I have a fact table that contains 3 mln records. The view takes about 8 minutes to run and joins to about 9 other tables (all have PK and joins are done on PKs) and there is also a small date exclusion.

```
SELECT k.Field
,l.Field 
--...
,z.field 
FROM dbo.Fact f
join DimRegion dr on dr.RegionKey = f.RegionKey AND dr.RegionName = 'UK' 
join DimDate dd on dd.DateKey = f.DateKey and dd.Date >= '2020-07-01'
join DimTable dt on dt.TKey = f.TKey and dt.isExcluded = 0
left join DimK dk on f.KKey = dk.KKey
--...
left join DimZ dz on f.ZKey = dz.ZKey
```

The query takes 90 seconds if I comment out all LEFT JOINs, and with each adding about 45 seconds time to run. All the joins are made using integer values.

I have rebuilt all the indexes that were fragmented, created index on the Date but this didn't help at all.
Here is the execution plan with the highest numbers:
[image]

Is there anything else I could do to speed it up or is the volume of data too large and that's why it takes so long?

here's the full plan (thanks @eshirvana):
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1tphqoEu

Comment: this is not the whole execution plan , paste it using https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and put the link in your question

Comment: The estimate vs actual rows are clearly way off and you appear to have a yellow bang. Need the full showplan xml really.

Comment: thanks guys, I have added the full plan

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning.

Comment: what is clear is on table "FactSnapshotOpportunity" stats are way off, are you sure stats are up todate  for that table

Comment: The estimated rows are way off which means memory grants are too low hence the spill to disk. You need to give the table and index definitions. You could try a `force order` hint to see if that helps which might give some clues.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to optimize a query that returns 2.3M rows to the client?

You should be filtering and aggregating the results on the server.  This query spent 3 minutes just to send all the results to the client, in addition to the 1.5 minutes of IO waits and 1 minute of CPU time.

```
        <WaitStats>
          <Wait WaitType="ASYNC_NETWORK_IO" WaitTimeMs="171313" WaitCount="189426" />
          <Wait WaitType="IO_COMPLETION" WaitTimeMs="66082" WaitCount="16620" />
          <Wait WaitType="IO_QUEUE_LIMIT" WaitTimeMs="49006" WaitCount="3433" />
          <Wait WaitType="RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="889" WaitCount="496442" />
          <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="430" WaitCount="5574" />
          <Wait WaitType="RESOURCE_GOVERNOR_IDLE" WaitTimeMs="162" WaitCount="19" />
          <Wait WaitType="MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="80" WaitCount="44521" />
        </WaitStats>
        <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="75783" ElapsedTime="481785" />
```

And why is your fact table a clustered index table instead of a [clustered columnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Clustered%20columnstore%20index.%20A%20clustered%20columnstore%20index%20is,a%20btree%20list%20of%20IDs%20for%20deleted%20rows.)?  Once you stop returning all the rows and columns to the client, a clustered columnstore should perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your help and ideas!
I have rebuilt the stats, and focused on indexes - especially the one to DimDate.
What has helped was changing this

```
...f.DateKey and dd.Date >= '2020-07-01'
```

to

```
...f.DateKey and f.DateKey >= 20200701
```

I have realised that after @Stu's comment to use *force order* (I've managed to figure out which index was failing me) it took a minute and half off, but fully skipping that index took half time (3.5 mins less) and the remaining time, as mentioned by @David Browne 3 mins are spent on sending full data to the client, I'm happy with that as most of the time it will be filtered by customer and dates so it actually takes seconds now.
Thank you once again.